# Creating Plot with Interactions in R

Tags: r, boxplot, interaction

I have a mixed-effects model and would like to plot it. Unfortunately, there are significant interactions on non-significant variables.

My formula is

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Adaptive Gauss-Hermite Quadrature, nAGQ = 0) ['glmerMod']
Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: Response ~ SIZE+ TYPE + ACTIVITY + X1000m_NR + (1 | ID) + (DISTANCE:1 | ID) + (SIZE:1 | ID) +  
    (GROUPTYPE:1 | ID) + (TYPE:1 | ID) + (ACTIVITY:1 | ID) + (X100m_NR:1 | ID) + (X400m_NR:1 | ID) + (X1000m_NR:1 | ID) + (O1000m_NR:1 | ID) + TYPE:ACTIVITY +  ACTIVITY:X1000m_NR
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+05))
```

My Anova says

```
Response: Response
                                Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
SIZE                          8.6671  1   0.003240 **
TYPE                          5.0478  6   0.537695   
ACTIVITY                      5.4717  5   0.361055   
X1000m_NR                     0.0000  1   0.999899   
TYPE:ACTIVITY                12.0274  3   0.007290 **
ACTIVITY:X1000m_NR           17.5623  4   0.001502 **
```

I intended to use a jitter boxplot, which fits nicely with the Response and SIZE, however I would like to add the interactions. It would be nice to add them to the boxplot, but a second graph would also be ok.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think interact_plot(model, pred = v1, modx = v2) may help